# How to include a Android values strings.xml file into another strings.xml

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to put all codes inside values-zh/strings.xml into values-zh-rCN/strings.xml. How do i do this?

I've tried this `<include layout="@values-zh/strings" />` but did not work, Intelij is telling me to declare the file first.

Comment: Why do you want to do this, it make no sense.

Comment: There are different variations for the simplified chinese language. I want them to be the same, so to avoid copy and pasting every time i need to make changes, I want to use Include instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `values-zh/strings.xml` is your base string resources, you can put all your strings there, and only provide values for those you need to override in `values-zh-rCN/strings.xml`.

In `values-zh/strings.xml`:

```
<string name="title">default title</string>
<string name="content">default content</string>
```

In `values-zh-rCN/strings.xml`:

```
<string name="title">simplified title</string>
```

Now when you are on simplified Chinese config, `content` will be 'default content', and `title` will be 'simplified title'.

Comment: Not exactly what Im looking for. Actually both are simplified chinese. I had to keep both because on some older android version, simplified chinese is using one of the two strings and if android can't find the exact version, it won't fall back to the other. So I need to have them exactly the same. And to keep maintenance minimum, I want only to modify one.